# Emacs: function that writes down an elisp code that adds a keybinding specified by the user

Tags: emacs, keyboard-shortcuts, elisp

How can I make an interactive function that interactively read a key from the user (like when you press C-h k) and then writes some line like this:

```
(global-set-key (kbd "C-x C-s") 'hello)
```

where the "C-x C-s" part is replaced appropriately with the read key.

[Some beginning users have problem making keybindings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/382811/emacs-keybinding-for-c) and in fact I get confused about it too, so I thought let's just automate it.

Comment: While the automation will help a little, I think the more frequent problem is that (new) users forget/don't know that `interactive` is required for commands.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This seems to work:

```
(defun insert-key (key)
  (interactive (list (read-key-sequence "Key: ")))
  (insert "(global-set-key (kbd \"" (key-description key) "\") 'hello)\n"))
```

Answer (score 0):

Huh? Maybe I'm misunderstanding the question, but if not, this is the answer: `global-set-key` is a ***command***. And it does just what is requested (IIUC): It reads a key sequence (type, click, etc.), and then it reads the command to bind the key sequence to.